# Different declarations of the lambda that capture the parameter inside the C++20 requires expressions

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider the following two simple concepts:

```
template <typename T>
concept C1 = requires(T t) {
  [t = t]{ t; };
};

template <typename T>
concept C2 = requires(T t) {
  [t]{ t; };
};
```

In my opinion, the two declarations should be equivalent, but GCC rejects the `concept C2` and says:

```
<source>:10:9: error: use of parameter outside function body before ';' token
```

[Why GCC only accepts the `concept C1`](https://godbolt.org/z/1rY1Wr), or this is just a bug? If not, what is the difference between those two declarations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *simple-capture* (like `[t]` in your second example) can only capture local variables and/or `this`. However, the parameters of a *requires-expression* aren’t local variables. That’s not an issue for *init-captures* (as in your first example).